# How do I specify file specific settings in VLC Media Player

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a video and a corresponding subtitles (.SRT) file.

Problem is, the timing is incorrect in the subtitles file. Whenever I play the video I  have to delay the subtitles by *n* msec in order for it to sync correctly according to the spoken dialogue. This process is cumbersome even with the shortcuts (keyboard 'g').

I have 2-3 videos with the same out-of-sync subtitles and it's difficult to remember how much delay is required by each video.

**Any possible way to automate this process?** Like adding metadata to a file or customizing VLC to recognize when this video is played and automatically delay the subtitles by the required amount?

Also, suggestions are welcome if there is a subtitle editor which automatically increases/ decreases all timings in an SRT file.

No, I cannot download any alternate copy of the SRT file since the video isn't public.

Edit: Yes, I'm a programmer so I don't mind you giving me pointers on how to go about this through a script as well. Does VLC have an API that can help with this automation? Documentation link please!

Comment: For a start, SRT is a text-based format. You can view the offsets in a text editor and modify them with any pattern-matching and string editing tool.